# How to fetch routes from app-routing module?

Tags: angular

I'm still learning angular so I'm not very comfortable with it yet. My question is the following: is there any way of fetching my routes array from app-routing.module.ts? Because I want to have a mat-tab-navbar with the routes I defined but in a specified component(not in app-component only), since I'm getting the error below:

Maybe there is a better solution that you could provide? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get those routes defined in the app.module you can use

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.routes = this.router.config;
}
```